# Prove the Morley's theorem via unconventional method

Tags: euclidean-geometry, axioms, origami

Well it's a little dream :Prove the [Morley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem) using unconventional method .

The idea is based on origamis and [Huzita–Hatori axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huzita%E2%80%93Hatori_axioms) . Well first the idea is to [trisecting an angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_paper_folding#Trisecting_an_angle) .This construction is due to Hisashi Abe . So we have an angle divided in $3$ equal angles . Now take the opposite corner take an arbitrary angle and make the same things . Now we have two side of the Morley's triangle . Then the idea is to prove that the other side of the Morley's triangle is formed via the missing trisectrix (last angle of the triangle). Well I have tried it some hours without success .

How to prove the Morley's theorem via the  construction  due to Hisashi Abe and origami ?

Thanks in advance !!

Ps:I shall open a bounty if there is a nice proof of it .

Comment: Hm, the axioms seem a bit weird to me. E.g., Axiom 5 states "There is .." and then it is discussed that this need not be the case? -- But more importantly, I do not see much proof-power in these axioms. Can you for example use them to prove the much simpler result that the perpendicular bisectors (i.e., the unique folds between each pair of vertices) in a triangle intersect in a single point? Or how would you even express "is an equilateral triangle"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well axiom 1 to 5 are not so important because we can use a compass for that . The axiom 6 is truly powerful and this is what we need to trisecting an angle .I think there is a hidden construction to show that we speak about the missing trisectrix .